# Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I followed code [SignalR guide for .NET CORE AngularApp](https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2)

I get below error:

> Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports

The code is there hosted on Microsoft's Github [here](https://github.com/singhvivek2503/SignalRWeb)

Below is code snippet from `Startup.cs` code:

```
public class Startup
{        
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:49446")
            .AllowCredentials();
            //.AllowAnyOrigin()

        }));
        services.AddSignalR();
       ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notifyhub");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

       ...
    }
}
```

My Hub class:

```
public class NotifyHub:Hub<ITypedHubClient>
{
    public NotifyHub()
    {

    }        
}
```

Angular `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, IHubProtocol} from     '@aspnet/signalr';

@Component({selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']})
export class AppComponent {
  public _hubConnection : HubConnection;

  msgs : Message[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() : void {
let builder = new HubConnectionBuilder();

this._hubConnection = builder
  .withUrl('/notifyhub')      
  .build();

this
  ._hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error :', err));;

  this
  ._hubConnection
  .on('BroadcastMessage', (type : string, payload : string) => {

    this
      .msgs
      .push({severity: type, summary: payload});
  });
 }
}
```

Not sure what am I missing here? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so issue was mismatch of `.NET Core` version and `@aspnet/signalr` version.

I am using .NET core version `1.0.0-preview1-final`
but `@aspnet/signalr` I was using was `1.0.0`.

So, I fixed the issue by changing the `@aspnet/signalr` version from `1.0.0` to `1.0.0-preview1-final` which fixed the issue. [Github](https://github.com/singhvivek2503/SignalRWeb) is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error after publishing it in IIS and everything works fine in development then - Go to Control panel -> Programs and features -> Turn windows features on or off. Then check the Websocket Protocol option inside Internet Information Service.

[Websocket Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaB7R.png)

(Worked for me)